# C# interface property implementation

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

```
interface IAlpha
{
    IBeta BetaProperty { get; set; }
}

interface IBeta
{

}

class Alpha : IAlpha
{
    public Beta BetaProperty { get; set; } // error here
}

class Beta : IBeta
{

}
```

> *'InterfaceTest.Alpha' does not implement interface member 'InterfaceTest.IAlpha.BetaProperty'. 'InterfaceTest.Alpha.BetaProperty' cannot implement 'InterfaceTest.IAlpha.BetaProperty' because it does not have the matching return type of 'InterfaceTest.IBeta'.*

My question is why is a property implementation restricted to the very same type. Why can't I use the derived type instead?

Comment: Your class that inherits the interface does  return a Beta insteed of a IBeta declared in the interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to implement the *exact* same interface. For example, this *should* be valid:

```
 IAlpha alpha = new Alpha();
 alpha.BetaProperty = new SomeOtherIBetaImplementation();
```

... but that wouldn't work with your code which *always* expects it to be a `Beta`, would it?

You can use generics for this though:

```
interface IAlpha<TBeta> where TBeta : IBeta
{
    TBeta BetaProperty { get; set; }
}

...

public class Alpha : IAlpha<Beta>
```

Of course, that may be overkill - you may be better just using a property of type `IBeta` in `Alpha`, exactly as per the interface. It depends on the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and for the alternative solution. :)

Comment: @Jon Keet. Why is it still not possible if the `IAlpha` interface only defines a getter on the BetaProperty? Any interface implementation would be always guaranteed to return an IBeta.

Comment: @user2697817: It's just the way .NET and C# are defined. You could use explicit interface implementation to implement `IAlpha` and then expose a more specific property getter with the same name though.

Answer (score 2):

An  interface declares a set of methods the class will have, so anyone using that interface knows what to expect.

So, if you're implementing that interface, you must implement the **exact** interface, so all the other users get what they expected.